# R dplyr function to calculate conditional distance

Tags: r, dplyr

A small question : how would you calculate the time distance between two points given a condition in R. Please see below a short example. The context is as follows, I have a set of firms, and these firms experience credit ratings downgrade at certain periods. How can I calculate the time since the last rating downgrade. Having Month and rating, I would like to obtain :

```
Data <- data.frame(
  Month = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12),
  rating = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3),
rating_change = c(0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0),
t_since_change = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,0,1,2,3,4,5,0,1)
)
```

Basically since I have a lot of firms, I do :

```
temp <- Data %>%
group_by(Firms, Month) %>%
mutate(rc = rating - lag(rating)) %>%
mutate(rating_change = ifelse(rc >0, 1,0))
```

But I do not manage to calculate `t_since_change`. Would anybody have an idea ?

Comment: You don't include `Firm` in your data. Also, try not grouping by `Month` that should fix at least the `rating_change` part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if this is what you want. I used data.table.

```
Data <- data.frame(
  Month = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12),
  rating = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3),
  rating_change = c(0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0),
)

library(data.table)

DT <- as.data.table(Data)

DT[, t_since_change := NA_integer_]

j <- 0

for (i in seq_len(nrow(DT))) {
  if (DT[i, rating_change] == 1) {
    DT[i, t_since_change := 0]
    j <- i
    next
  }
  
  if (j == 0) {
    next
  }
  
  DT[i, t_since_change := (i - j)]
  
}
```

Output:

```
> DT
    Month rating rating_change t_since_change
 1:     1      1             0             NA
 2:     2      1             0             NA
 3:     3      1             0             NA
 4:     4      1             0             NA
 5:     5      2             1              0
 6:     6      2             0              1
 7:     7      2             0              2
 8:     8      2             0              3
 9:     9      2             0              4
10:    10      2             0              5
11:    11      3             1              0
12:    12      3             0              1
```

Answer (score 1):

The code below should work with your data:

```
library(tidyverse)
Data <- data.frame(
  Month = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12),
  rating = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3)
)


Data %>% 
  mutate(change = rating > lag(rating)) %>% 
  mutate(last_change = Month * ifelse(is.na(change), NA, ifelse(change, TRUE, 
NA)) ) %>% 
  fill(last_change) %>% 
  mutate(time_since = Month - last_change)
```

Comment: Thank you that is exactly what I was looking for, this is brilliant, I was missing the "fill" function !